# Remote light switches for light bulbs

Tags: home-automation

I live in an apartment wherein one of the rooms the light switch is outside of the room, which is annoying. I would like to add 2 light switches inside the room that would be used instead of the one outside and would turn on and off the lights.

In the ceiling, I have 2 240V compact fluorescent lights that are wired in series. One thing is that I'm looking for a solution that is comprised of switches mounted on the wall, rather than a remote controller that is moved around.

What product would you suggest me to buy and use for this?

Comment: we don't make product recommendations, but there's plenty of commercial solutions to your proposed problem, so you don't really need one anyway.

Comment: I beg to differ that there is a reason to ask for product recommendations. Had it been just one product I wanted to buy, I would research the options and pick one. But I am finding out for myself that this field is complicated and requires multiple solutions - a switch, toggle, and hub. The problem is that not all options work with each other, so a recommendation here is much needed and appreciated.

Comment: @AlonMln -- if you think that a hub is required, *you aren't looking hard enough*.  I know offhand that Insteon can work with just a switch and a remote; likewise with Lutron Caseta.

Comment: Are the two lights really wired in series?

Comment: Yes they are wired in series

Answer (score 3):

### Steam technology:

You'll need to pull a bunch of cables through walls. Some of these will be 4-core.  I can say with great confidence it's illegal to do this without landlord permission.

### Smart-switch technology:

This is simplicity itself.  They make smart switches which work with wireless remote switches that run on batteries, have no wires, and simply stick to the wall.  You need to reconnoiter which wires are present in the old switch box to aid in product selection.

1. Get facilities/landlord permission to replace a switch.  It's unlikely they'd object.
2. Install such a brand of smart switch in the old/former switch location.
3. Install 2 remotes and pair them to the smart switch.

---

The key to finding masters and remotes that work with each other is **they will almost certainly be the same brand**.

Further, you should be aware that anything from the following channels is all but guaranteed to be the unsafe, illegal junkstream of poorly made goods from Alibaba:  a) AliExpress, b) eBay, c) DealExpress, d) Banggood, and e) Amazon Marketplace (pretty much anything on Amazon, sadly).  So you can save a lot of time/confusion by avoiding these channels altogether.

Honestly your best bet is your local home improvement retailer's web site (e.g. Wickes or Menards), or actually walk in to your local lighting supply house or electrical supply.  They will seem very expensive because they sell a higher quality product that is properly safety certified, and they charge a higher markup than mail order, *but they don't charge shipping*.  It is worth paying them for their knowledge if your time is valuable.  Having a good relationship with an electrical supply house is invaluable when doing projects, because they will save you a fortune by steering you away from expensive mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can you specify specific products that will work with each other? I have started to research this area and it seems that there are a lot of options, but many don't work with each other

Comment: @AlonMln I've added some buying advice.

Comment: We don't do specific product advice here.  Just make sure your two remote switches are the type that can simply double stick tape to the wall in the given locations.  At worst it should be screwed in without needing to cut into the drywall.  The LL should be happy with your work, though has the right to insist an electrician with a licence change the switch.  Buy them as a set, then they all play nice with each other.